# No custom fields form in wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Yesterday I moved my Wordpress blog to a new domain. Everything was easy enough to do and everything works, but the admin panel in my new installation doesn't show the custom fields form on the add new post page.

My theme practically shows everything with custom fields and it is still showing the meta values in the old imported posts but not the form, even when I edit the old posts. Is it a bad installation? I can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: have your checked if the option is activated? http://ottopress.com/2011/wp-quickie-metaboxes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out. **Wordpress.com's JetPack Plugin** came installed along with WordPress. I disabled it and the screen options just showed up. From screen options everything was unchecked for some reason. Custom fields is also showing up now. So many things were missing I just didn't notice everything. Slug was missing, Excerpt was missing, got it all now.

Thanks all...appreciate you guys taking the time to help me..

Answer (score 10):

There is a panel near the top of the screen when you are editing a post that says "screen options".

You can check to enable the custom fields again on that panel.

This panel is similar to the dashboard screen options and I think it's actually relatively new...

Comment: Something is seriously wrong. There is no screen options and I have been seeing it for ages. There was a WordPress update I installed it but still no use.

Comment: what version are you running now (from the version number at the bottom of the page to the right) ?

Comment: I got it thanks...Screen Option and Help both were missing as long as the 'JetPack by WordPress.com' plugin was enabled. All back now.

Comment: great. Glad you got it sorted out